# Is there a way to list down all the issues using github api without a page size?

Tags: github-api

I am using github apis to export a list of issues for a selected repository. For this, I am using python script. After getting a list of issues, I'd create a csv file. I just wanted to know if there is a way to extract all the issues at once using the github api? I have tried the following URL but it defaults to 30 and if I change the page size to more than 100, it still returns a maximum of 100 issues.

`https://api.github.com/repos/SS-priv/himalayan_pink/issues?per_page=1000`

Comment: If the repository has more than 100 issues, you will have to make multiple API calls to fetch all issues. There's no way around that. However, some  client libraries (e.g., https://github.com/sigmavirus24/github3.py) will do the work for you. For example, check out the `#iter_issues` method in github3.py (http://github3py.readthedocs.org/en/master/repos.html). /cc @sigmavirus24

Comment: @jasonrudolph Thats what I thought. I was thinking if there is a way to avoid so many calls. I did look at github3.py code. In the background, they are also calling the API multiple times. Anyways, seems like calling the API multiple times is the only way for now. Thanks for your help. Appreciate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All web API have a limit on the maximum number of elements they return per request as a safeguard against DDoS attacks. In the case of the github API, it seems to be limited to 100 elements per request, and there is nothing you can do about it. Just use multiple API calls and assemble the results.

Comment: Thank you. Thats seems to be the only solution for now. Appreciate your help here.